# Class placed on web component does not persist when toggled with mwc-tab-bar

Tags: web-component, lit

Using lit element 2,

I notice when I toggle in the tabs with mwc-tab-bar, the `class="hide"` on `<transactions-element class="hide"></transactions-element>` does persist.

Why is this?

```
  render() {
    return html`
      <mwc-tab-bar @MDCTabBar:activated="${this._setCurrentTabView}">
        <mwc-tab
        data-el="transactions-element"
        label="transactions"></mwc-tab>
        <mwc-tab
        data-el="foo-element"
        label="foo"></mwc-tab>
      </mwc-tab-bar>

      <div class="main">
        <main>${this._renderCurrentView()}</main>
      </div>
    `
  }

  _setCurrentTabView(e) {
    const {index} = e.detail;
    const tabs = this.renderRoot.querySelectorAll('mwc-tab');
    const { el } = tabs[index].dataset;
    this._fadeOutPage(this.currentView);
  }
  
  _renderCurrentView() {
    switch (this.currentView) {
      case 'transactions-element':
        import('./transactions-element.js');
        return html`<transactions-element></transactions-element>`;
      case 'foo-element':
        import('./foo-element.js');
        return html`<foo-element></foo-element>`;
      default:
        import('./not-found-view.js');
        return html`<not-found-view></not-found-view>`;
    }
  }

  _fadeOutPage(el) {
    const fromEl = this.renderRoot.querySelector(el);
    fromEl.classList.add('hide');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any time _renderCurrentView is called and changes will be destroyed.
It's better to update a stateful property and re-render

Add a reactive property (e.g hideTransactionelement)

Set in:

```
_fadeOutpage(el){
 this.hideTransactionelement = true;
}
```

import classmap into module
https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#classmap

and update render

```
const classes = { hide: this.hideTransactionelement };

return html`<transactions-element class=${classMap(classes)}  ></transactions-element>`;
```

Comment: Does this mean every time _renderCurrentView the webcomponent will be stamped over and over?

Comment: not sure what you mean by stamped.
but when i said "destroyed", that wasn't completely accurate,
transactions-element will be updated

You can try putting logging in component or 
 other life cycle constuctor,https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/

or add the current time to a render to see when it updates